# MVC Javascript objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I'm writing an API and website which displays charts of data.  I've written an abstracted 'Chart' object, which has things like a Series collection, various display options, and other stuff you'd expect to find on a Chart object.

I'm using this abstracted Chart object to allow users of my API to create a chart which the API can format into numerous different outputs.  For example, it can use MSCharts to create a chart image, then populate it with the appropriate settings from my own abstracted chart object.

I'm also trying to get it so that my website portion of this project can output a nice dynamic JavaScript chart using jqPlot.  My initial plan was to have an MVC Partial view which took my Chart object as a model, and translated this into JavaScript.  This became an awful pain to format, jumping into Razor code to make decisions, dropping out to output JavaScript and so on.

```
$.jqplot("chart", data, {
    @if (chart.Animate) { <text>animate: true,</text> }
    @if (chart.Animate) { <text>animateReplot: true,</text> }
    title: '@Model.Title',                
...
```

This is relatively basic, but when you get as far as spitting out series formatting information, it becomes unreasonably complex and not something I want to maintain.

My next plan was that an MVC action could just output the entire chart object using `return Json(...`

That works quite nicely to a point (C# code)

```
chart = new
{
  animate = abstractedChart.Animate,
  animateReplot = abstractedChart.Animate,
  title = v.Title,
  axes = new
      {
      xaxis = new
           {
```

...

But it falls over when you get to formatting the series.  jqPlot wants me to do something like this:

```
series: [{
    renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
....
```

I can't think of a way of outputting a "reference" to a JavaScript object from MVC in this way.

At this point, I'm starting to think I might need to write something to spit out raw JavaScript, and just shove that in my Partial View using `Html.Raw()` but, I keep thinking there must be a better way.

So that's my question - is there a better way?

Comment: C# <--> Javascript in MVC is something I struggle with as well.  Great question.  I hope a decent answer turns up.  Tomorrow I'm going to start investigating Roslyn for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering javascript code via partial views is hard to maintain, the second choice is much cleaner. The chart JSON should be as independent from JS rendering library as possible, so you can change the library in future without touching the MVC code. The final piece to make it work would be a javascript mapper from chart JSON to jqplot-specific input. Something like this:

```
var jqPlotMapper = {
    mapOptions : function (chartOptions)
    {
        return { seriesDefaults:{
                renderer: this.getSeriesRenderer(chartOptions.chartType)
        }};
    },    
    getSeriesRenderer : function (chartType)
    {
        switch(chartType)
        {
            case "line": return $.jqplot.LineRenderer;
            case "bar": return $.jqplot.BarRenderer;    
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var chart = {};
    chart.Data = [[2, 6, 7, 10]];
    chart.Options = { chartType: "bar"};
    plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', chart.Data, jqPlotMapper.mapOptions(chart.Options));
});
```